# Can't find where background color it set in Laravel 9 system

Tags: php, css

In my Laravel9 system there are parts with background color I want to change.
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzi8j.jpg
and this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUXvj.jpg
But I can not find where the color is defined.
In one blade there is a row like this:

```
<div class="row padding-top-50 padding-bottom-50 background-color-primary text-white">
```

If I remove "background-color-primary " the background color is removed. But I can't find where the background-color is set to color value.
Anybody know?

Comment: Have you got Angular or Vue set up, seems like it's a predefined class somewhere in there.

Comment: There's must be a css librairy in your project and then the background-color-primary is associated to a blue/green color

Comment: Did you try to check with inspect element browser tool to check where the style is ?

Comment: I would recommend you to please use inspect element and check all possible classes or ids which are adding color to you div

Answer (score 0):

I found it in public/css/# app.css where I changed to 337ab7. So now I have all background parts in Moderate blue and it looks really nice.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oZQS.jpg
Thanks guys!